# How to delete folders from SDCard during uninstalling of my app in Android?

Tags: android, storage, external, directory

I went through the following [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#ExternalCache) which says that the external folders will be deleted automatically during uninstallation of my app.

I am using the following code to create the folders and file:

```
private static String TEMP_FOLDER_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myAppFolder/";
```

My problem is that the folder myAppFolder is not getting deleted when I uninstall the app.

Am I going wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Save it in your Apps Private Folder (/data/data/*yourappPackege*). This folder will be removed when uninstalling the App.
You can get your private Folder with the Method `getFilesDir()`
Other files can not be removed because your App does not "know" when it is being removed.

Comment: this works thank you the only thing I need to do is change the path name by appending /Android/data/myappPackage

Answer (score 1):

Hey the link says that If you use getExternalCacheDir(), then only folders auto deleted when uninstalling the app. So please correct your self. If you are using **getExternalStorageDirectory** , then you have to manually delete the folder by programming

to delete a folder you can use below code

String TEMP_FOLDER_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myAppFolder/";

```
    File f1=new File(TEMP_FOLDER_PATH);
    f1.delete();
```

Comment: How do I do that programmatically .. i am in your case how can I delete folders from sdcard when my app is uninstalled

Comment: Thats fine... thank you but how do i detect when the application is uninstalling

Answer (score 0):

No. The Android OS does not remove the SDCard files corresponding to one App when the App is uninstalled.

Answer (score -1):

see this work for delete

```
    public static boolean deleteDirectory(File path) {
if( path.exists() ) {
  File[] files = path.listFiles();
  if (files == null) {
      return true;
  }
  for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
     if(files[i].isDirectory()) {
       deleteDirectory(files[i]);
     }
     else {
       files[i].delete();
     }
  }
}
return( path.delete() );
```

}