# Delete Folder from SDCARD when Unistall App

Tags: android, directory, uninstallation, android-sdcard

Here I created one Android Application which download images from web and store images in Folder which located on SDCARD. When I Uninstall my Android Application I want to delete that Image Folder.

Please Help me.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513997/how-to-delete-folders-from-sdcard-during-uninstalling-of-my-app-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an arbitrary location on the SDCard, use the recommended external storage directory, you can get a File link to this by calling:

```
getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

This is automatically removed when your app is uninstalled.

I've added an example below of creating a new file in the external storage directory:

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); 
String fileName = "file.txt"; 
File f = new File(baseDir + "/" + fileName);
```

Comment: You mean to say When i create a folder, create a folder with Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().

Comment: I've edited the example to show creating a new file in the external storage directory.

Comment: i created file with Your Example but When i uninstall my App it will not delete. my file is exist there.

Comment: Same with me, this will not delete the sdcard folder